# ArcSDE installation; "sdesetup: command not found"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, installation

I am trying to install ArcSDE component for postgresql database from A DVD file.

I have copied files of following folders on the server :

1. `command_64`
2. `pg_64`

in both of theses files there are `install` files. for both I used :

```
./install -load 
yes
mount point: DVD location or wherever you are installing from
install directory: enter to accept /home/sde
Package numbers to load: enter to accept all
yes
no
```

now I have sdeexe101 file which contains bin, etc, liband locale folders in it.

I also  As the root user, copied the st_geometry.so, libsg.so, and libpe.so files from $SDEHOME to the lib directory in the postgres location.

```
[root@machine pgsql]# cp /home/sde/sdeexe101/lib/st_geometry.so /usr/lib/pgsql
[root@machine pgsql]# cp /home/sde/sdeexe101/lib/libsg.so /usr/lib/pgsql
[root@machine pgsql]# cp /home/sde/sdeexe101/lib/libpe.so /usr/lib/pgsql
```

when I tried to execute sdesetup to create geodatabase and authorize it using:

```
sdesetup -o install -d POSTGRESQL -u sde -p sde...
```

I got this:
**`sdesetup: command not found`**

Are pg_64 and commands_64 files that I needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be in the position of having done too much research.  You are conflating documentation at different product releases, and making the installation process much harder than it should be as a result.

It is not necessary to install the "command_64" media if you are installing
the full "pg_64" media.  It is, in fact, not necessary to install any application server media at all (which is where the "no need for arcsde" fallacy originates).

ArcSDE is a protocol, and an application server that runs that protocol, but
is is also a technology that is used to seamlessly implement Esri versioned geodatabases in a dozen different RDBMS engines.  In order to create a
geodatabase at 10.1, you **must** run the [Enable Enterprise Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000160000000)
tool (either the UI tool or the Python equivalent) -- this will install
ArcSDE components into the database and make it a functioning geodatabase.
The pre-installation steps involve using the support libraries from the
Desktop or Server installation (not the application server install, which
does not have the PG 9.1 support files), and placing them in the support
library directory for the database install.

You may certainly install the application server on the database server,
or the ArcGIS Server application server, or on another host, though there
are licensing considerations (any host other than ArcGIS Server would
require purchasing additional software seats).

After the geodatabase is successfully enabled within PostgreSQL, you must
also [register that database with the ArcGIS Server install](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000505000000), so that
enterprise geodatabase sources are available.

You might be best served at this point with removing all but ArcGIS 10.1sp1
media from your system, and starting over from scratch with a PG 9.1.9
binary release.  Then you can copy the 10.1sp1 PG 9.1 support files from
a Desktop 10.1sp1 or AGS 10.1sp1 install. Then run the Enterprise GDB tool.
Then you can populate data, and register the database with that data
for use by ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 1):

I never do more than a vanilla install of ArcSDE but I found this in its **[online help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w00000031000000)** and suspect that it may be relevant:

> At ArcGIS 10.1, there is no ArcSDE Post Installation wizard, and the
>   installation operation is no longer supported with the **sdesetup**
>   command.